# React - autocomplete search for API - array always returns empty

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to make an autocomplete search for Alpha Vantage API, but the array which should contain the matches (suggestion) always returns empty when I type in the input field and I don't know what could be the reason, I'm stuck for a while on this and would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

The related code here is mostly in useEffect and the inputHandler:

```
const Search = () => {

 useEffect(() => {
        const getSymbols = async () => {
            const searchURL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=${textInput}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY}`

            const res = await axios.get(searchURL);

            if(res) {
                setSecurity(res.data.bestMatches);
                if(security !== undefined  && security.length > 0) {
                    let symbols = security.map(sec => sec['1. symbol'])
                        setAllSymbol(symbols);
                }
            }
        }

        getSymbols();
       
    }, [])

    console.log(allSymbol);
    
    const inputHandler = (e) => {
        setTextInput(e.target.value);

        let matches = [];
                
        if(textInput.length > 0) {
           matches =  allSymbol.filter(sym => {
                 const regex = new RegExp(`${textInput}`, "gi");
                 return sym.match(regex);
             })
             setSuggestion(matches);
             
         }
         console.log(suggestion);
        setTextInput(e.target.value); 
    }

    const showData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const searchURL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=${textInput}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY}`
        const monthlyURL = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol=${textInput}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY}`

        try {
            const res = await axios.get(searchURL);
            const data = await axios.get(monthlyURL);
            
            if(res) {
                setTickers(res.data.bestMatches[0]);
                setSymbol(res.data.bestMatches[0]['1. symbol']);
                setSecurity(res.data.bestMatches);
                
                if(data) {
                    const monthlyTimeSeries = Object.values(data.data['Monthly Time Series']);
                    const result = [monthlyTimeSeries[1]];
                    const resultValues = Object.keys(result[0]).map(key => {
                        return Math.floor(result[0][key]);
                    })
                    setPrices(resultValues);
                }
            }
            
           } catch(err) {
               console.log(err)
           }

           setDailyPrices([]);
           setWeeklyPrices([]);
           setIntraPrices([]);
    } 
    
    return (
        <StyledSearch>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <h1>Security Price Monitor App </h1>
                <form onSubmit={showData} className="search-form">
                    <input type="text" value={textInput} onChange={inputHandler} placeholder='Enter Stock Symbol (GOOG, MSFT)'/>
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            
            {prices.length > 0 && (
                <>
                 <Table prices={prices} symbol={symbol}/>
                 <TimeFrames symbol={symbol} textInput={textInput} weeklyPrices={weeklyPrices} setWeeklyPrices={setWeeklyPrices} dailyPrices={dailyPrices} setDailyPrices={setDailyPrices} intraPrices={intraPrices} setIntraPrices={setIntraPrices} />
                </>
            )}
            
        </StyledSearch>

    )
}
```

Comment: The first thing I see here is your empty deps array in the useEffect. Is it wanted? Since you didn't put `textInput` in that array, it will be executed only once after the first render.

Comment: also, I think you will need some debounce value here to limit api calls